# Can you modify the styles in a Word document through Office.js?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, office-js

Is it possible to programmatically, from a Word Add-in, change the styles of a document?

For instance, set the "Normal" style to be a font size 18?

Specifically, I'm interested in modifying the BubbleText style settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no API to change an existing style. This is known issue and we will expose it in the future.

Comment: Thanks Juan...

I can change much of the formatting through OOXML, but size of the font (because it's controlled by BalloonText style) isn't adjustable - even by the user in a comment (you can't just select text and make it bigger - which has always seemed like awful UX to me...).